# 18.04 upgrade does not install desktop

Tags: upgrade

my upgrade finished but when I log on all I get is the cmd prompt. there is not a desktop installed. How do I fix this?

Comment: I tryed the command ‘startx’ and it loaded the gui and the command prompt is gone. Now it all works fine until I reboot, then I have to use startx again. So the gui is installed and working but ubuntu starts in terminal mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1.

If there is still no GUI type: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to install GUI programs that come with Ubuntu. Wait until it downloads reboot and that should solve it I guess.

Comment: All he has is the command prompt so no need for Ctrl+alt+f1 to open another one.